# Why is this Angular JS filter removing spaces?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm making a tiny app to learn Angular, and have made a custom filter for text processing.  Everything is working fine, except that in cases when my output text has multiple spaces, these get automatically reduced to a single space, which I don't want.  The issue is not in the function I've defined, because I'm logging the output, which does not have the problem.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" ng-model="encodeText" placeholder="Type or paste in a message to encode." ></textarea>
<p>Filtered input: {{ encodeText | encode }}</p>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.filter("encode", function() {
    return function(input) {
      if (input) {
        //text processing
        console.log(output);
        return output;
      }
    };
 });
```

It is a Morse Code exercise.  So console log output is:

```
.- -... -.-.   -.. . ..-.
```

With two spaces.  On the page I see:

```
Filtered input: .- -... -.-. -.. . ..-.
```

The only suggestion I'm seeing from Googling is using ng-trim="false" on the textarea, which has no effect.  It seems the trimming is happening within the filter itself.  What is causing this and how do I disable it?  [Code repo](https://github.com/brian-davis/angular-morse-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p`format your output.
Try:

```
<pre>{ encodeText | encode }</pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

By default, HTML doesn't preserve multiple whitespaces (collapses them into 1 space). Add a style to the `<p>` tag to [preserve whitespace](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)...

```
<p style="white-space: pre">Filtered input: {{ encodeText | encode }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works seems to have some minor cross-browser issues.