# angular trimmed input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got some issues with ng-model and input element. Please take a look at this plunker: `http://plnkr.co/edit/PJCv1AsPns1cxuSPTZiU`

My point is when I edit the input value and add some white spaces at the beginning and at the end f.e.

```
    some text
```

and click `save` the white spaces are trimmed (and it's OK) from `inputValue`, but if I edit it again the "previous" white spaces appear in the input. How to prevent it? I tried to do this with

```
angular.element($('#trimInput')).val($scope.inputValue);
```

and it works, but I don't like this solution.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('trim', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.inputValue = "some text";  
    $scope.editMode = false;
    
    $scope.edit = function() {
      $scope.editMode = true;  
    };
    
    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.editMode = false;  
      //angular.element($('#trimInput')).val($scope.inputValue);
      console.log($scope.inputValue);
      console.log($scope.inputValue.length);
    };
    
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="trim">
    <div ng-show="!editMode">
      [{{inputValue}}]
      <button ng-click="edit()">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="editMode">
      <input id="trimInput" type="text" ng-model="inputValue" />
      <button ng-click="save()">save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: downvoted because you're avoiding the rules by adding the plunkr link and no code

Comment: fix the model value, not the dom element value

Comment: but the model has no white spaces, they appear only in input element

Answer (score 0):

By default `ng-trim` is `true` in angular so it will automatically trim value in scope. But value will not update on `input`, means extra input will be there. You have to manually assign it.

```
$document[0].getElementById("trimInput").value = $scope.inputValue;
```

For this you need to inject `$document` in your application. This is automatically assign trim value to input when you save.

[**See DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/As0oaDAylJ9Ym23L29dx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var temp=document.getElementById('trimInput');
console.log(temp.value);
$scope.inputValue=temp.value
```

and 
  [Why is this Angular JS filter removing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964573/why-is-this-angular-js-filter-removing-spaces)